# How can i handle radio button?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

this is backend code for radio button

```
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="notification_pref" title="" value="1" 
  class="notifyRadio" checked=""><p>By Email</p>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="radio" name="notification_pref" title="" value="2" 
  class="notifyRadio"><p>By Text Message - Message and Data Rates May 
  Apply</p>
</div>
```

How can I handle this radio button?

Comment: What is a "back-end" code? Do you have some trial that failed?

Comment: <div><input type="radio" name="notification_pref" title="" value="1" class="notifyRadio" checked=""><p>By Email</p></div>
<div><input type="radio" name="notification_pref" title="" value="2" class="notifyRadio"><p>By Text Message - Message and Data Rates May Apply</p></div>

i have tried select method, by name, by xpath

Answer (score 1):

You work with radio buttons like you would work with a regular `WebElement`.

1. Locate the element: `WebElement myRadio = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='radio'][@value='1']"));`
2. Perform a click: `myRadio.click();`

The code above locates your first radio-button and selects it.

**UPD:** There are a number of approaches that you can use to skip selection of already selected buttons (which one to use depends on your particular need). For example you can take all radio-buttons:

```
List<WebElement> allButtons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='radio']"));
```

and then iterate over the list to click first unselected button:

```
for(WebElement button: allButtons){
    if(!button.isSelected()){
        button.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: buddy, it didn't work. as value 1 is already checked but wants to check value 2.

Comment: when u change to 2 does that work ?

Comment: @Sufiyaan then you call `isSelected` to check if the element was already selected. and click if it was not.